# Scala printSchema not working when reading excel file

Tags: excel, scala, apache-spark, schema

Goal is retrieve correct schema from different tables, but the code below in Scala is not working.

```
spark.sqlContext.read.format("csv")
.option("header", "true")
.option("inferSchema", true)
.load("CERT_YHEIL_PROJECTS_PREP (1).xlsx").printSchema**strong text**
warning: 1 deprecation (since 2.13.3); for details, enable `:setting -deprecation` or `:replay -deprecation`
root
 |-- PK\b!A{曧�\a�[Content_Types].xml ��(�ĕMO�@����^Q�����p����R���I��~igɿg��P�b��l��3���r�]�m\f�8�Ǣ����aވ���F�D���Q.h�P\NO�L��\t��耍h��w)Q���1A�7���"��s��^�9������1Q�!��0SKG��?ސdp(����Ϋ*%g�"&���s=;�Y�`k�2��[�7�6x����dk��U���g\f�r�1����n�-�q6�L�K��1eP[�.k�: string (nullable = true)
```

Comment: `excel` files cannot be read as `csv` format!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to load excel file using the csv reader which is wrong.
In order to load excel file into a DataFrame, try to use the [Spark Excel](https://github.com/crealytics/spark-excel) connector:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import com.crealytics.spark.excel._

val spark: SparkSession = ???
val df = spark.read.excel(
    header = true,  // Required
    dataAddress = "'My Sheet'!B3:C35", // Optional, default: "A1"
    treatEmptyValuesAsNulls = false,  // Optional, default: true
    setErrorCellsToFallbackValues = false, // Optional, default: false, where errors will be converted to null. If true, any ERROR cell values (e.g. #N/A) will be converted to the zero values of the column's data type.
    usePlainNumberFormat = false,  // Optional, default: false. If true, format the cells without rounding and scientific notations
    inferSchema = false,  // Optional, default: false
    addColorColumns = true,  // Optional, default: false
    timestampFormat = "MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss",  // Optional, default: yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss[.fffffffff]
    maxRowsInMemory = 20,  // Optional, default None. If set, uses a streaming reader which can help with big files (will fail if used with xls format files)
    maxByteArraySize = 2147483647,  // Optional, default None. See https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/5.0/org/apache/poi/util/IOUtils.html#setByteArrayMaxOverride-int-
    tempFileThreshold = 10000000, // Optional, default None. Number of bytes at which a zip entry is regarded as too large for holding in memory and the data is put in a temp file instead
    excerptSize = 10,  // Optional, default: 10. If set and if schema inferred, number of rows to infer schema from
    workbookPassword = "pass"  // Optional, default None. Requires unlimited strength JCE for older JVMs
).schema(myCustomSchema) // Optional, default: Either inferred schema, or all columns are Strings
 .load("Worktime.xlsx")
```

Comment: thanks to both. Tried this one and also read as csv coverting the xlsx file previously and worked as well. One question how can adapt this code to read the table if got multiples sheet and without knowing before hand how many and the name of each sheet

Comment: You can't read a file without knowing about it, you can use any scala excel lib to discover the spreadsheets of an excel file and decide what to do with the result. Anyway, I would leave it for a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

Spark can't read excel files so you have 2 options:

1. Use pandas to read and then convert it to a Spark DataFrame (Example code below)
2. Convert it manually to csv using the "Save As" option in Excel or any other online tool

Prerequisits:

```
# Install library that pandas can use to read the excel 
pip install xlrd
```

```
import pandas as pd 

pdf_excel = pd.read_excel("CERT_YHEIL_PROJECTS_PREP (1).xlsx")

df = spark.createDataFrame(pdf_excel)

df.printSchema()
df.show()
```